# How to quit my job while not burning the bridge?

Tags: resignation

I received a job offer today that comes with a substantial raise in pay, as well as title and responsibilities. I originally applied for the position assuming I would never get it (they were looking for someone with almost three times the experience I have, and with experience in technologies I am barely familiar with at that) There is no way I cannot accept the offer, but I feel terrible about leaving.

My current company took a huge chance on me, hired me while I was still taking courses in school (Software Development industry), and has treated me very well for the most part the entire time I have been with them. For instance, I was looking at a cross country move and they offered to let me go remote, with a cost of living wage increase at the same time.

The problem is that not long before that, they basically doubled my salary. When this happened, the CEO mentioned that as long as I didn't end up leaving in six months, he considered the raise a good thing. Unfortunately, it's been just about 6 months from that conversation.

I want to see your opinions on how I can resign from my current position without burning any bridges in the process. FWIW, most of my current team, boss aside, knows about my intent to leave and supports my reasoning.

Comment: "`they were looking for someone with almost three times the experience I have, and with experience in technologies I am barely familiar with at that). There is no way I cannot accept the offer`" Did you discuss these short fallings form the job description at the interview? Are you absolutely certain the new company will not be "upset" when they discover them (especially unfamiliarity with the technology to be used)?

Comment: @gnat - Similarities, but I think the idea of the pay increase is a new point.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the people in your immediate department understand your position, and since it would be your line manager who would write any reference, their view will be the most relevant.

Since the CEO mentioned - it sounds to me jokingly - about you leaving in six months, if your rapport with them is good you could approach them directly, apologise, and reassure them that there wasn't a problem with their company - the opportunity was just too good to miss. You could do that, but it's not necessary.

A point to consider - your company doubled your salary because they knew they were underpaying you for the work you were doing. It wasn't an act of charity. This is reinforced by another company being willing to pay you even more. The idea of you leaving for more pay is something they've considered before.

A good employer will have no problem with the idea of a valued member of staff moving on for better pay and greater responsibilities.